# How to show ImageView over the bottom of CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

Struggling with xml. I want to show `RoundedCornerImageView` over `CardView`'s bottom. Having a hard time to implement it.

Here is snap how i want layout to look like

[image]

Here is `xml` for what i have tried so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is Title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
            android:text="This is content.This is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <com.softoven.ultron.util.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work for you:

1) With `RelativeLayout` as root view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is Title"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <TextView
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                    android:text="This is content.This is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.softoven.ultron.util.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) With `LinearLayout` as root view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/container">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:id="@+id/card"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="This is Title"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textColor="#000"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
                            android:text="This is content.This is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is content"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.softoven.ultron.util.RoundedImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: The perfect one.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Use **android:elevation** attribute to show imageview over cardview.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.softoven.ultron.util.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    **android:elevation = "5dp"**
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>
```

Comment: >= API 21 only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` to achieve the desired behavior. Please use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is Title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#c5c5c5"
            android:text="This is content.This is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <com.softoven.ultron.util.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/card"/>
```

See if this helps you.

Comment: I tried that but it align on the bottom of parent layout which is relative layout according to your solution. I want to place it over CardView's bottom

Comment: Problem is that image roundedImage's bottom is align with cardView. I want to align Half of image over cardView.

Comment: set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to `RoundedImageView` and remove `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/card"` to `RoundedImageView`

Comment: now its in the center of parent layout. Not over the cardView

Answer (score 0):

change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and put ImageView  on your CardView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="This is Title"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="This is content.This is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is content"
                android:textColor="#c5c5c5" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir change 
  android:paddingTop="20dp" to   android:paddingTop="-20dp"

Answer (score 0):

Put your `imageview` inside `RelativeLayout` and give `margintop` as negative value(-20dp) and cardview in another relative layout.
Put these two relative layout inside a relative layout:

```
<RLMain>

<RL1>
 <CV></CV>
</RL1>

<RL2>
<IV></IV>(give margintop in -ve value (-20dp))
</RL2>

</RLMain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Card View in a Relative Layout alone then Use Linear Layout as a Parent for both Image and our Relative Layout and use negative margin :)
Try this:

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="This is Title"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="This is content.This is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is contentThis is content"
                    android:textColor="#c5c5c5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/service_flag" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with giving elevation in Constraintlayout. ***android:elevation*** attribute allows you to change z-axis.

> https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:src="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card_editor_shop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_editor_shop" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_editor_shop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```